# how to memcpy() a constant

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I memcpy() a constant in c++
for example I have defined a constant using

```
#define constant1 0x0080
```

when i want to

```
memcpy(&some_memory_block, constatnt1, 2 );
```

it says

```
error C2664: 'memcpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'const void *'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a constant, instead of a precomiler definition.

```
const unsigned short int constant1 = 0x0080;
memcpy(&some_memory_block, &constant1, 2 );
```

Comment: Looks like the OP wants a `uint16_t` rather than an `unsigned int`.

Comment: The u in uint is for unsigned. The size of int is not specified, but rather chosen by the compiler. but i'll adjust it to make it more cross compiler working...

Answer (score 3):

Your constant (macro) is really just a literal. As such, it has no address which could be given as parameter to `memcpy` or another function that expects a memory location. If you want to do this, you need to have a *real constant* (such as `const int`), as suggested in the other answers.
A real constant as opposed to a macro (which is just a text substitution, in this case for a literal) is normally functionally identical to a literal, as long as you don't take its address. However, it is possible to take its address, at which point it behaves like a "normal" variable. Which means that you *can* use `memcpy` on its address.

The usually "more correct" answer, however, is: Don't do this kind of thing at all. If something is a constant, you shouldn't copy it around (there exist exceptions of course, but usually you just shouldn't). The only valid reason would be that you want a constant value to initialize a non-constant variable, but then it's much easier to just assign it than to `memcpy`.

Making copies of a constant otherwise only adds redundancy, eats up extra memory at no benefit, increases cache pressure, and defeats many compiler optimizations. For example, a compiler can trivially optimize an expression like `a = b + c - c + b` to `a = computed_value_of_2b` if it knows that the symbols are constants (much more complicated and less obvious expressions are evaluated too, of course). However, the compiler has to emit code that evaluates at runtime when given some memory locations, it has no other choice.

Answer (score -1):

What happen in your case is that constant1 gets replaced by 0x0080 when you compile the code.
And this line

```
memcpy(&some_memory_block, constatnt1, 2 );
```

becomes

```
memcpy(&some_memory_block, 0x0080, 2 );
```

this

If you look at [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) you will see that memcpy requiers a pointer for the second parameter.

You have to assing a pointer to the memcpy

```
const int constant1 = 0x0000;
memcpy(&some_memory_block, &constant1 , 2 );
```

Comment: address value will not become a direct const  value.